Velocity field in the Reynolds transport theorem
Let $f: [0,1]\times \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $\{\Omega_t\}_{t\in [0,1]}$ be characterized by a collection of functions $\{h_t\}_{t\in [0,1]}$ such that
$$
\Omega_t = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^d:h_t(x)\leq 0\}.
$$
To apply the Reynolds transport theorem, we need to find the velocity field w.r.t the boundary $\partial\Omega_t$. My question is expressing the velocity field in terms of $h_t$ (assuming all smoothness if necessary). How can I approach the problem in this case? I have searched online but it seems in most applications, the velocity field is given a prior. Any reference or answer will be appreciated!

The surface, presumably given by $h_t(x)=0$, moves with the flow. It’s easiest to work with a reference configuration.

Could you elaborate on the reference configuration here? When that $\nabla h_t$ corresponds to the unit outer normal vector field, our idea is to characterize the flow by $\nabla h_{t+s}^{-1}\circ \nabla h_t$, which gives rise to a collection of curves pining down the movement of the boundary points.

See any introduction to continuum mechanics or, if you prefer, fluid mechanics.

Thanks, that will be helpful!
